# In Visual Studio 2010, intellisense isn't showing for long method signatures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

The problem is exactly as asked in the question title.

When I'm typing in the text editor and referencing a public method that has a long signature (lots of parameters, usually 10 or more) the intellisense just stops working.  It will sometimes flicker; other times it will not show at all.

Only seen this happen with C#, but I don't use anything else.  It might happen in VB too.  Don't know.

Anyone else seeing this?

I've Googled for an hour but can't seem to iron it out.  I've restarted VS, rebooted the machine, enabled/disabled intellisense in Tools -> Options.  NOTHING works.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Have you checked relevant bug/fix report pages on MSDN? If you can't find anything there, I'd suggest emailing the .NET team.

Comment: This would have been reported before at connect.microsoft.com, programmers care a lot for IntelliSense.  Nothing resembles your issue.  If you can repro this on another machine then file your own report.  Be sure to be very specific with a framework method example.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's driving me mad.

Comment: Why is the question getting voted down?  Every time I re-check this thread, the question's vote count gets lower.  The problem really exists, and it's been confirmed as happening by dozens of other people.  I've asked it on other forums and seen others say the same thing.  If anything, since no one appears to be able to fix it, the question's vote count should be going _up_.

Answer (score 3):

You can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to bring it back up.

Even better, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> copies it to the clipboard.

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> pastes it. Handy for templates.

Comment: That's it!  Brilliant that someone would answer this question more than a year after I asked it.  I wish I could give you two votes.

Comment: Haha. Ya, I just happen to be bored and was clicking random related links.

Comment: Actually, no, that wasn't it.  Your answer provides a cool tool I never knew about before (so +1 for that) but the underlying problem still remains.  When you have a really long method signature (lots of params) the intellisense malfunctions.

Comment: Odd, I'm not sure what the limit is for the Signature tool tip.  I've seen up to eight line so far.  This will be a fun test. . .

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered one cause for the problem.
If the method is at the top of the screen, it pops downwards.
If the method is at the bottom of the screen is pops upwards.
However in the middle of the screen if it's too big to go either way it gets confused - flickers or just won't open.

Unfortunately, no matter what I do I can't seem to get it to display more than 37 parameters...

Found a partial solution - change the font size
Was supposedly scheduled to be fixed in SP1...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/e2f06f24-0b68-48f3-a8b3-c31948f6e168